# How to create batch file for copy command?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, combine, copy

I'd like to combine two files together using the copy command as follows. This is simple enough using

**copy /b base.txt + file1.txt combined_file1.txt**

however the first part of the file (base.txt) will remain constant and the second half will be from a folder full of different file (such as file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt etc)

The output file should be the variable filename with **combined_** added at the front.

I'd like a batch file that I can place inside the directory of files and have it automatically add base.txt to the front of all the other variable files.

Comment: Is Powershell and option? if so this one-liner might start you off: `Get-ChildItem "Files" -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object { (gc base.txt) + (gc ("files\"+$_.Name) ) | out-file -filepath ("files\combined_"+$_.Name)}` base.txt is in the `root` with a `files` folder containing the files.

Comment: The way this place works, is that you post the script that you wrote, that doesn't work, and we tell you what's wrong with it. Maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a powershell script that will do it. Just adjust the base path and the combined folder and the files folder.

```
$baseFilename = "c:\temp\base.txt"
$addonFolderLocation = "c:\temp\files"
$combinedFolderLocation = "c:\temp\combined\"

#Get all files in addon folder location
$addonFilenames = Get-ChildItem $addonFolderLocation

foreach ($addonFilename in $addonFilenames)
{
    cat $baseFilename, $addonFilename.fullname | sc "$combinedFolderLocation combined_ $addonFilename"
}
```

edit: added combined_ before filename in combined output

Comment: That's absolutely perfect, just tried it and it does exactly what I needed. I Googled this for quite some time and couldn't find any other post which addressed my question. Many thanks for your kind help.